# Workaround Google Chrome Extension 800px limit on iframe

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a workaround for the 800px width limit for iframes on google chrome extensions when the button is adjacent to the URL bar? Even if it's something I can change on my end only. It's for personal use...

Comment: is this a popup frame you get when you click on a button next to the URL bar, or a sidebar, or...?

Comment: It's next to the URL bar. I'd like to be able to extend the sizing past 800px.

Comment: Ah, the pop-up for a Page Action or Browser Action, you mean. Don't think it's possible, no. There's nothing in the API specifying these dimensions, and setting CSS for `html` and `body` creates a scrollbar for anything larger than `800px`. Think you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks Chris, if you'd place your response as an answer, I'll accept it. I've found similar questions on SO with no workaround available. So it looks like it's a limitation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Chris mentioned, you cannot change the frame size beyond 800px. However there is a way to make your extension run in a new tab instead of a extension frame...

In your `background page`, call a function to open a new tab when the `extension icon` is clicked:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.create(
      {url:"chrome-extension://################################/popup.html"}
    );    
});
```

NOTE: You need your `extension ID` to replace the 32 #'s and whichever filename you would like to open replace 'popup.html'... ALSO, be sure to remove `"popup": "popup.html"` from your manifest file, so that the extension doesn't try to first load in a frame...

Comment: Use `chrome.extension.getURL("popup.html")` rather than hardcoding the extension's ID in the URL.